# CSS3 Linkedin like Preloader animation simulate using @keyframes not working

Tags: css, keyframe

i work with css very rarely. i got a nice `CSS3 Preloader` animation which is not working. here i am submitting the code. please some one tell me which area causing the issue.

```
<div class="initial-load-animation">
  <div class="linkedin-image"></div>
  <div class="loading-bar">
    <div class="blue-bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>


@keyframes initial-loading {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: translate(-34px,0)
    }
  50% {
    transform: translate(96px,0)
    }
}
```

full code in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/pcvfxk2p/1/ get me some help please.

Comment: Your css code uses nested selectors. AFAIK non of the browsers support it out of the box. You need to preprocess it using say sass https://jsfiddle.net/pcvfxk2p/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted is SCSS, a way to more easily write CSS. This needs to be compiled into CSS before you can use it in your browser. I compiled it for you. Try this one:

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

@keyframes initial-loading {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: translate(-34px, 0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(96px, 0);
  }
}
.initial-load-animation {
  padding-top: 96px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform .5s ease;
}
.initial-load-animation .linkedin-image {
  background-image: url(https://static.licdn.com/sc/h/6m22ya0r3as5388b95jkuk1mv);
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  margin: 0 auto 32px;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
}
.initial-load-animation .loading-bar {
  width: 130px;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #cfcfcf;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: rotateY(0);
  transition: transform .3s ease-in;
}
.initial-load-animation .loading-bar .blue-bar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 68px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-34px, 0);
  background-color: #0073b1;
  border-radius: 2px;
  animation: initial-loading 1.5s infinite ease;
}
.initial-load-animation .fade-load .linkedin-image {
  transform: translate(0, 10px);
  opacity: 0;
}
.initial-load-animation .fade-load .loading-bar {
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="initial-load-animation">
  <div class="linkedin-image"></div>
  <div class="loading-bar">
    <div class="blue-bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the meaning of -webkit-animation ? and what is -moz-animation ?

Comment: what is the meaning of these below code `*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}`

Comment: Google is your friend. There are thousands of questions concerning this. Useful queries: *what are vendor prefixes css*, *what does box-sizing border-box do*, *SCSS*.

Comment: i found answer for -webkit and -moz. here it is `#mainbox { 
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;  /* Safari */
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;    /* Firefox\Gecko Engine */
  -o-border-radius: 5px;     /* Opera */
  border-radius: 5px;
}` comment given for css line for vendor wise css.

Comment: Exactly. However, these days it's not necessary for border-radius or box-shadow. Vendor prefixes are only still needed with very new features. Consult [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/) to see if you can use a feature in your browser or need a prefix.

Answer (score 1):

You've had some spare { in your CSS code. But this is working https://jsfiddle.net/pcvfxk2p/7/

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

@keyframes initial-loading {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-34px,0)
    }
  50% {
    transform: translate(96px,0)
    }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-34px,0)
  }
}

.initial-load-animation {
  padding-top: 96px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform .5s ease;
 }

  .linkedin-image {
    background-image:url(https://static.licdn.com/sc/h/6m22ya0r3as5388b95jkuk1mv);
    height: 48px;
    width: 48px;
    margin: 0 auto 32px;
    transform: translate(0,0);
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all .5s ease-out;
      }

  .loading-bar {
width: 130px;
height: 2px;
margin: 0 auto;
border-radius: 2px;
background-color: #cfcfcf;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 1;
transform: rotateY(0);
transition: transform .3s ease-in;
}    

.blue-bar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 68px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-34px, 0);
  background-color: #0073b1;
  border-radius: 2px;
  animation: initial-loading 1.5s infinite ease;
}



  .fade-load {

.linkedin-image {
  transform: translate(0, 10px);
  opacity: 0;
}

.loading-bar {
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
}

}
```

Comment: i am weak in css. tell me the meaning of nested css class `.fade-load {
 .linkedin-image {

 }

 .loading-bar {

 }
}`  how it works or what is the meaning of nested css class ?